# Summation Notation for a Linear Combination with a Break in the Index.

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, notation

I am trying to write a linear combination with an index running from 1 to 10, however, neglecting the index 5. I currently wrote the following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{4}c_{i}\phi _{i}+\sum_{i=6}^{10}c_{i}\phi _{i}$$
Is there a proper way to express this linear combination in a single sum, or is convention to keep it as expressed above (two sums)? My knowledge of notation for sums is limited, so I apologize if this is an easy question. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If the upper and lower limits are understood from context, some might write $\sum_{i \ne 5} c_i \phi_i$, but this has some ambiguity. Some less ambiguous ways are
$$\sum_{\substack{1 \le i \le 10 : \\i \ne 5}} c_i \phi_i$$
or
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} c_i \phi_i - c_5 \phi_5.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something in the spirit of
$$
\sum_{i=1, i\neq 5}^{10}\cdots 
$$
this is well defined.
For me your notation is cleaner.